# Polar H10 to RPI Zero W: HR Notifications stop after ca. 100s without error message

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, raspberry-pi-zero

I'm using pygatt on a RPI Zero W to access the HR notification stream from a Polar H10 chest belt. The goal is to let an LED blink with the heart rate. Notifications arrive for ca. 100s, then none arrive anymore. No error messages or any (for me recognizable) hint is shown in the debug log.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

The used code is:

````
from pygatt.util import uuid16_to_uuid
from pygatt.exceptions import NotConnectedError, NotificationTimeout
import binascii
import time
import logging
import RPi.GPIO as gpio

MAC = 'E7:17:FD:20:B1:AA'   # MAC address of the Polar H10 belt
HR = 0
RRi1 = 0
RRi2 = 0
LED_On_time = 0.15       # seconds
GPIO_port = 19
gpio.setmode(gpio.BCM)
gpio.setup(GPIO_port, gpio.OUT)

logging.basicConfig(filename='/home/pi/python/debug.log',filemode='w',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('pygatt').setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def callback(handle, measure):
    global HR, RRi1, RRi2

    if handle == 16:
        for i in range(len(measure)):
            if i == 1:
                print('Heart rate = ',measure[1],' bpm')
                HR = measure[1]
            if i == 2:
                RRi1 = round((measure[2] + 256*measure[3])/1024,2)
                print('RR intervall = %.2f' % RRi1,' s')
            if i == 4:
                RRi2 = round((measure[4] + 256*measure[5])/1024,2)
                print('RR intervall = %.2f' % RRi2,' s')


def Init():

    adapter = pygatt.GATTToolBackend()
    adapter.start()

    try:
        """ connect to bluetooth MAC addres with 5 seconds timeout"""
        device = adapter.connect(MAC, address_type=pygatt.BLEAddressType.random)
        device.bond()

        """ generate characteristics uuid's  """
        uuid_heart_service = uuid16_to_uuid(0x2A37)
        """ discover all characteristics uuid's"""
        device.discover_characteristics()


        device.subscribe(uuid_heart_service, callback, True)

    except NotConnectedError:
        print('No connection established ')
        quit()



Init()
t = time.time()    # Initialite with a reasonable value
while(1):
    gpio.output(GPIO_port, gpio.HIGH)
    time.sleep(LED_On_time)
    gpio.output(GPIO_port, gpio.LOW)
    time.sleep(max(0, 60/max(HR,30) - (time.time() - t)))    
    t = time.time()```
````